# While deploying on app engine error is "too big (35193367 bytes). Max file size is 33554432 bytes."

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
> File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ize-testenv.appspot.com/8ed0be2ac2cbbdc375ac3eee3195746862391a54 failed with: File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ize-testenv.appspot.com/8ed0be2ac2cbbdc375ac3eee3195746862391a54 is too big (35193367 bytes). Max file size is 33554432 bytes.
>
> Details: [
> [
> {
> "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
> "description": "File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ize-testenv.appspot.com/8ed0be2ac2cbbdc375ac3eee3195746862391a54 is too big (35193367 bytes). Max file size is 33554432 bytes.",
> "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.ize-testenv.appspot.com/8ed0be2ac2cbbdc375ac3eee3195746862391a54",
> "resourceType": "file"
> }
> ]
> ]

I manually increased react build size with "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8192 build" so in local it's getting build fine. Is this the reason for this error?

Can I increase staging area max file size?

I tried optimizing react app. I got GLTF files that's why react app is that big.

So i'm ignoring node_modules In .gcloudignore :
node_modules
.gitignore
**/.DS_Store

and in cloudbuild.yaml :
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'client'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run','build']
  env:

  - 'NODE_ENV=production'
    dir: 'client'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'server'

## Step 3: Deploy to App Engine

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy','client/clientAppEngine.yaml','server/serverApp.yaml']

Comment: Can you share your folder trees and the command you use to deploy your app? I suspect that you include the node_module directory in the package to deploy.

Comment: So i'm ignoring node_modules In .gcloudignore : 
node_modules
.gitignore
**/.DS_Store

and in cloudbuild.yaml :
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install']
    dir: 'client'

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['run','build']
    env:
      - 'NODE_ENV=production'
    dir: 'client'

  # Step 3: Deploy to App Engine
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy','client/clientAppEngine.yaml']

Comment: What do you want to deploy? the dist directory? Do you need the module at runtime? Don't forget that a `gcloud app deploy` run a new Cloud Build behind the scene. So, in your Cloud Build you recreate the node module directory (with your build step) and it's this one that break your App Engine deploymenet (it is uploaded to app engine).

Comment: okay got it but we do have to write that step npm install in build step right??

Comment: Yes, `build` entry point is called at build time, and the `start` entry point is called at runtime https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#npm_build_script

Comment: so what can i do to solve this ? Can we increase limitation given by GCP that is 33MB ??

Comment: No, you can't increase the limit. Did you try a `gcloud app deploy` directly from your environment? and not from Cloud Build.